Помогите с SVG плиз!
Обясните пожалуйста кто-то, что я делаю не так???
почему не отображается ни одна svg иконка?? просто белая страница, ошибок в консоли 0....
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>SVG</title>
</head>

<body>
    <svg display="none">
        <symbol id="MySpace" viewBox="0 0 37 24">
            <path d="M80.7645419,1767.27837 C80.7645419,1765.65605 81.8549935,1763.99308 82.6946065,1763.15812 C84.6339613,1761.23037 87.6405419,1760.56379 89.8864774,1761.89695 C90.6308645,1762.33941 91.0187355,1762.61115 91.6109935,1763.1976 C93.696671,1765.26237 93.5015742,1767.11347 93.5015742,1769.58702 C93.5015742,1769.95863 93.3157677,1770.14444 92.9441548,1770.14444 L81.3219613,1770.14444 C80.9503484,1770.14444 80.7645419,1769.95863 80.7645419,1769.58702 L80.7645419,1767.27837 Z M68.0275097,1755.81412 L68.0275097,1756.45166 C68.0275097,1758.85554 70.4000258,1761.22805 72.8038968,1761.22805 L73.4402839,1761.22805 C75.8453161,1761.22805 78.216671,1758.85554 78.216671,1756.45166 L78.216671,1755.81412 C78.216671,1753.41141 75.8453161,1751.03889 73.4402839,1751.03889 L72.8038968,1751.03889 C70.4000258,1751.03889 68.0275097,1753.41141 68.0275097,1755.81412 Z M68.0275097,1768.47218 C68.0275097,1769.43954 67.8568,1770.14444 68.584929,1770.14444 L77.6604129,1770.14444 C78.3873806,1770.14444 78.216671,1769.43954 78.216671,1768.47218 C78.216671,1765.54341 76.3051871,1762.50199 73.4402839,1762.50199 L72.8038968,1762.50199 C69.9459613,1762.50199 68.0275097,1765.54689 68.0275097,1768.47218 Z M57.8371871,1758.36199 C57.8371871,1757.12173 58.7894452,1755.80134 59.9577032,1755.22883 C61.3942194,1754.52508 63.2488,1754.8096 64.3880258,1755.95115 C65.3031226,1756.86508 65.4796387,1757.81386 65.4796387,1758.99954 C65.4796387,1761.88883 61.3872516,1763.86883 58.9288,1761.41037 C58.0160258,1760.49644 57.8371871,1759.54766 57.8371871,1758.36199 Z M57.8371871,1767.43747 L57.8371871,1769.58702 C57.8371871,1769.95863 58.0229935,1770.14444 58.3946065,1770.14444 L64.9222194,1770.14444 C65.2938323,1770.14444 65.4796387,1769.95863 65.4796387,1769.58702 C65.4796387,1767.78354 65.7200258,1766.37373 64.3473806,1764.98715 C63.2708645,1763.90134 62.7935742,1763.77476 61.3396387,1763.77476 C59.5349935,1763.77476 57.8371871,1765.95915 57.8371871,1767.43747 Z M80.7645419,1753.26741 C80.7645419,1755.36237 81.3080258,1756.79773 82.6156387,1758.10418 C85.0961548,1760.58586 89.1699613,1760.58586 91.6516387,1758.10418 C94.1333161,1755.6225 94.1333161,1751.54986 91.6516387,1749.06818 C89.1722839,1746.58883 85.1008,1746.58186 82.6156387,1749.06818 C81.7295742,1749.95425 80.7645419,1751.5336 80.7645419,1753.26741 Z" ></path>
        </symbol>
    </svg>
    <svg display="none">
        <symbol id="opera" viewBox="0 0 46 48">
            <path
                d="M76.0071624,615 C62.9300139,615 53,624.094835 53,638.771068 C53,651.451456 62.1984833,663 75.9993379,663 C89.8033224,663 99,651.451456 99,638.771068 C98.9998796,624.111728 89.0845517,615 76.0071624,615 L76.0071624,615 Z M76.0065605,619.240194 C83.4104644,619.240194 84.9162595,629.23899 84.9162595,638.318097 C84.9162595,646.72835 84.078436,657.987728 76.0974451,657.987728 C68.1164542,657.987728 67.0844627,646.618136 67.0844627,638.208583 C67.0844627,629.130175 68.6019344,619.240194 76.0065605,619.240194 L76.0065605,619.240194 Z">
            </path>
        </symbol>
    </svg>
    <svg display="none">
        <symbol id="Share" viewBox="0 0 44 44">
            <path d="M61.855,422.51 C63.681,422.51 65.363,421.885 66.697,420.838 L81.603,428.197 C81.603,428.227 81.601,428.254 81.601,428.283 C81.601,432.621 85.119,436.139 89.457,436.139 C93.794,436.139 97.312,432.621 97.312,428.283 C97.312,423.946 93.794,420.428 89.457,420.428 C87.148,420.428 85.074,421.422 83.638,423.006 L69.582,416.067 C69.664,415.61 69.71,415.139 69.71,414.656 C69.71,414.559 69.707,414.463 69.703,414.367 L84.244,406.731 C85.632,407.961 87.457,408.711 89.457,408.711 C93.796,408.711 97.312,405.194 97.312,400.856 C97.312,396.516 93.794,393 89.457,393 C85.119,393 81.601,396.516 81.601,400.856 C81.601,401.18 81.625,401.498 81.662,401.811 L67.533,409.231 C66.103,407.735 64.089,406.801 61.855,406.801 C57.517,406.801 54,410.319 54,414.656 C54,418.994 57.517,422.51 61.855,422.51"></path>
        </symbol>
    </svg>
    <svg display="none">
        <symbol id="twitter" viewBox="0 0 48 39">
            <path
                d="M319.08654,68.7148754 C319.708094,82.5659738 309.37992,98.0092879 291.095386,98.0092879 C285.534424,98.0092879 280.357954,96.3781513 276,93.5841073 C281.223647,94.1997641 286.439039,92.7514374 290.5788,89.505676 C286.270382,89.4266549 282.633053,86.5795371 281.38051,82.6674038 C282.92319,82.9622586 284.441103,82.876161 285.82692,82.4999263 C281.090373,81.5469556 277.822203,77.2809966 277.92835,72.7190034 C279.256376,73.4561404 280.775468,73.8996019 282.390093,73.9491375 C278.003833,71.0194604 276.761905,65.2285125 279.342474,60.8021524 C284.198142,66.7605779 291.453929,70.6809671 299.639098,71.0925844 C298.203745,64.9312988 302.876603,59 309.232493,59 C312.065458,59 314.624797,60.1947516 316.419873,62.1089488 C318.663128,61.6678461 320.77075,60.8481498 322.673153,59.7194457 C321.938375,62.019313 320.376824,63.9500221 318.343506,65.1671827 C320.335545,64.9301194 322.23323,64.4005602 324,63.6174259 C322.68023,65.592953 321.010172,67.3266991 319.08654,68.7148754">
            </path>
        </symbol>
    </svg>


    <svg class="icon">
        <use xlink:href="#MySpace"></use>
    </svg>
    <svg class="icon">
        <use xlink:href="#opera"></use>
    </svg>
    <svg class="icon">
        <use xlink:href="#Share"></use>
    </svg>
    <svg class="icon">
        <use xlink:href="#twitter"></use>
    </svg>
</body>

</html>


Теперь всё отображается, но в css , fill я менять могу, f а fill:hover не реагирует(((
вот новый код:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>SVG</title>
</head>

<body>
    <svg display="none">
        <symbol id="MySpace" viewBox="0 0 37 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" >
                <g id="Social-Icons---Isolated" transform="translate(-57.000000, -1747.000000)" >
                    <path d="M80.7645419,1767.27837 C80.7645419,1765.65605 81.8549935,1763.99308 82.6946065,1763.15812 C84.6339613,1761.23037 87.6405419,1760.56379 89.8864774,1761.89695 C90.6308645,1762.33941 91.0187355,1762.61115 91.6109935,1763.1976 C93.696671,1765.26237 93.5015742,1767.11347 93.5015742,1769.58702 C93.5015742,1769.95863 93.3157677,1770.14444 92.9441548,1770.14444 L81.3219613,1770.14444 C80.9503484,1770.14444 80.7645419,1769.95863 80.7645419,1769.58702 L80.7645419,1767.27837 Z M68.0275097,1755.81412 L68.0275097,1756.45166 C68.0275097,1758.85554 70.4000258,1761.22805 72.8038968,1761.22805 L73.4402839,1761.22805 C75.8453161,1761.22805 78.216671,1758.85554 78.216671,1756.45166 L78.216671,1755.81412 C78.216671,1753.41141 75.8453161,1751.03889 73.4402839,1751.03889 L72.8038968,1751.03889 C70.4000258,1751.03889 68.0275097,1753.41141 68.0275097,1755.81412 Z M68.0275097,1768.47218 C68.0275097,1769.43954 67.8568,1770.14444 68.584929,1770.14444 L77.6604129,1770.14444 C78.3873806,1770.14444 78.216671,1769.43954 78.216671,1768.47218 C78.216671,1765.54341 76.3051871,1762.50199 73.4402839,1762.50199 L72.8038968,1762.50199 C69.9459613,1762.50199 68.0275097,1765.54689 68.0275097,1768.47218 Z M57.8371871,1758.36199 C57.8371871,1757.12173 58.7894452,1755.80134 59.9577032,1755.22883 C61.3942194,1754.52508 63.2488,1754.8096 64.3880258,1755.95115 C65.3031226,1756.86508 65.4796387,1757.81386 65.4796387,1758.99954 C65.4796387,1761.88883 61.3872516,1763.86883 58.9288,1761.41037 C58.0160258,1760.49644 57.8371871,1759.54766 57.8371871,1758.36199 Z M57.8371871,1767.43747 L57.8371871,1769.58702 C57.8371871,1769.95863 58.0229935,1770.14444 58.3946065,1770.14444 L64.9222194,1770.14444 C65.2938323,1770.14444 65.4796387,1769.95863 65.4796387,1769.58702 C65.4796387,1767.78354 65.7200258,1766.37373 64.3473806,1764.98715 C63.2708645,1763.90134 62.7935742,1763.77476 61.3396387,1763.77476 C59.5349935,1763.77476 57.8371871,1765.95915 57.8371871,1767.43747 Z M80.7645419,1753.26741 C80.7645419,1755.36237 81.3080258,1756.79773 82.6156387,1758.10418 C85.0961548,1760.58586 89.1699613,1760.58586 91.6516387,1758.10418 C94.1333161,1755.6225 94.1333161,1751.54986 91.6516387,1749.06818 C89.1722839,1746.58883 85.1008,1746.58186 82.6156387,1749.06818 C81.7295742,1749.95425 80.7645419,1751.5336 80.7645419,1753.26741 Z" id="MySpace"></path>
                </g>
            </g>
        </symbol>
    </svg>
    <svg display="none">
        <symbol id="opera" viewBox="0 0 46 48">
            <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1">
                <g id="Social-Icons---Isolated" transform="translate(-53.000000, -615.000000)">
                    <path d="M76.0071624,615 C62.9300139,615 53,624.094835 53,638.771068 C53,651.451456 62.1984833,663 75.9993379,663 C89.8033224,663 99,651.451456 99,638.771068 C98.9998796,624.111728 89.0845517,615 76.0071624,615 L76.0071624,615 Z M76.0065605,619.240194 C83.4104644,619.240194 84.9162595,629.23899 84.9162595,638.318097 C84.9162595,646.72835 84.078436,657.987728 76.0974451,657.987728 C68.1164542,657.987728 67.0844627,646.618136 67.0844627,638.208583 C67.0844627,629.130175 68.6019344,619.240194 76.0065605,619.240194 L76.0065605,619.240194 Z"></path>
                </g>
            </g>
        </symbol>
    </svg>
    <svg display="none">
        <symbol id="Share" viewBox="0 0 44 44">
            <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1">
                <g id="Social-Icons---Isolated" transform="translate(-54.000000, -393.000000)">
                    <path d="M61.855,422.51 C63.681,422.51 65.363,421.885 66.697,420.838 L81.603,428.197 C81.603,428.227 81.601,428.254 81.601,428.283 C81.601,432.621 85.119,436.139 89.457,436.139 C93.794,436.139 97.312,432.621 97.312,428.283 C97.312,423.946 93.794,420.428 89.457,420.428 C87.148,420.428 85.074,421.422 83.638,423.006 L69.582,416.067 C69.664,415.61 69.71,415.139 69.71,414.656 C69.71,414.559 69.707,414.463 69.703,414.367 L84.244,406.731 C85.632,407.961 87.457,408.711 89.457,408.711 C93.796,408.711 97.312,405.194 97.312,400.856 C97.312,396.516 93.794,393 89.457,393 C85.119,393 81.601,396.516 81.601,400.856 C81.601,401.18 81.625,401.498 81.662,401.811 L67.533,409.231 C66.103,407.735 64.089,406.801 61.855,406.801 C57.517,406.801 54,410.319 54,414.656 C54,418.994 57.517,422.51 61.855,422.51"></path>
                </g>
            </g>
        </symbol>
    </svg>
    <svg display="none">
        <symbol id="twitter" viewBox="0 0 48 39">
            <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1">
                <g id="Social-Icons---Isolated" transform="translate(-276.000000, -59.000000)">
                    <path d="M319.08654,68.7148754 C319.708094,82.5659738 309.37992,98.0092879 291.095386,98.0092879 C285.534424,98.0092879 280.357954,96.3781513 276,93.5841073 C281.223647,94.1997641 286.439039,92.7514374 290.5788,89.505676 C286.270382,89.4266549 282.633053,86.5795371 281.38051,82.6674038 C282.92319,82.9622586 284.441103,82.876161 285.82692,82.4999263 C281.090373,81.5469556 277.822203,77.2809966 277.92835,72.7190034 C279.256376,73.4561404 280.775468,73.8996019 282.390093,73.9491375 C278.003833,71.0194604 276.761905,65.2285125 279.342474,60.8021524 C284.198142,66.7605779 291.453929,70.6809671 299.639098,71.0925844 C298.203745,64.9312988 302.876603,59 309.232493,59 C312.065458,59 314.624797,60.1947516 316.419873,62.1089488 C318.663128,61.6678461 320.77075,60.8481498 322.673153,59.7194457 C321.938375,62.019313 320.376824,63.9500221 318.343506,65.1671827 C320.335545,64.9301194 322.23323,64.4005602 324,63.6174259 C322.68023,65.592953 321.010172,67.3266991 319.08654,68.7148754"></path>
                </g>
            </g>
        </symbol>
    </svg>


    <svg class="icon">
        <use xlink:href="#MySpace"></use>
    </svg>
    <svg class="icon">
        <use xlink:href="#opera"></use>
    </svg>
    <svg class="icon">
        <use xlink:href="#Share"></use>
    </svg>
    <svg class="icon">
        <use xlink:href="#twitter"></use>
    </svg>
</body>

</html>

CSS:
.icon {
    display: block;
    fill: green
};

.icon:hover {
    fill: red;
}


Прежде чем его опубликовать, рекомендуем ознакомиться с справкой о том, как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Ну как минимум даже без проверки сразу по координатам видно, что <path> находится за пределами указанного viewBoxи соответственно быть видимым никак не может

всё поменял, исправил, всё отображается... в CSS цвет fill задать могу, а вот fill:hover не работает((((

@Alkani4, загрузите исправленный код

@Alkani4, а почему у Вас код начинается с <html lang="en">? Он должен начинаться с <!DOCTYPE html>

сори, плохо скопировал.... незаметил. Спасибо

Всё отлично работает, если быть чуточку внимательнее - ставить точку с запятой, где это нужно и не ставить, где попало ;-)


.icon {
  display: block;
  fill: green;
}

.icon:hover {
  fill: red;
}
<svg display="none">
  <symbol id="MySpace" viewBox="0 0 37 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" >
      <g id="Social-Icons---Isolated" transform="translate(-57.000000, -1747.000000)" >
        <path d="M80.7645419,1767.27837 C80.7645419,1765.65605 81.8549935,1763.99308 82.6946065,1763.15812 C84.6339613,1761.23037 87.6405419,1760.56379 89.8864774,1761.89695 C90.6308645,1762.33941 91.0187355,1762.61115 91.6109935,1763.1976 C93.696671,1765.26237 93.5015742,1767.11347 93.5015742,1769.58702 C93.5015742,1769.95863 93.3157677,1770.14444 92.9441548,1770.14444 L81.3219613,1770.14444 C80.9503484,1770.14444 80.7645419,1769.95863 80.7645419,1769.58702 L80.7645419,1767.27837 Z M68.0275097,1755.81412 L68.0275097,1756.45166 C68.0275097,1758.85554 70.4000258,1761.22805 72.8038968,1761.22805 L73.4402839,1761.22805 C75.8453161,1761.22805 78.216671,1758.85554 78.216671,1756.45166 L78.216671,1755.81412 C78.216671,1753.41141 75.8453161,1751.03889 73.4402839,1751.03889 L72.8038968,1751.03889 C70.4000258,1751.03889 68.0275097,1753.41141 68.0275097,1755.81412 Z M68.0275097,1768.47218 C68.0275097,1769.43954 67.8568,1770.14444 68.584929,1770.14444 L77.6604129,1770.14444 C78.3873806,1770.14444 78.216671,1769.43954 78.216671,1768.47218 C78.216671,1765.54341 76.3051871,1762.50199 73.4402839,1762.50199 L72.8038968,1762.50199 C69.9459613,1762.50199 68.0275097,1765.54689 68.0275097,1768.47218 Z M57.8371871,1758.36199 C57.8371871,1757.12173 58.7894452,1755.80134 59.9577032,1755.22883 C61.3942194,1754.52508 63.2488,1754.8096 64.3880258,1755.95115 C65.3031226,1756.86508 65.4796387,1757.81386 65.4796387,1758.99954 C65.4796387,1761.88883 61.3872516,1763.86883 58.9288,1761.41037 C58.0160258,1760.49644 57.8371871,1759.54766 57.8371871,1758.36199 Z M57.8371871,1767.43747 L57.8371871,1769.58702 C57.8371871,1769.95863 58.0229935,1770.14444 58.3946065,1770.14444 L64.9222194,1770.14444 C65.2938323,1770.14444 65.4796387,1769.95863 65.4796387,1769.58702 C65.4796387,1767.78354 65.7200258,1766.37373 64.3473806,1764.98715 C63.2708645,1763.90134 62.7935742,1763.77476 61.3396387,1763.77476 C59.5349935,1763.77476 57.8371871,1765.95915 57.8371871,1767.43747 Z M80.7645419,1753.26741 C80.7645419,1755.36237 81.3080258,1756.79773 82.6156387,1758.10418 C85.0961548,1760.58586 89.1699613,1760.58586 91.6516387,1758.10418 C94.1333161,1755.6225 94.1333161,1751.54986 91.6516387,1749.06818 C89.1722839,1746.58883 85.1008,1746.58186 82.6156387,1749.06818 C81.7295742,1749.95425 80.7645419,1751.5336 80.7645419,1753.26741 Z" id="MySpace"></path>
      </g>
    </g>
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="opera" viewBox="0 0 46 48">
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1">
      <g id="Social-Icons---Isolated" transform="translate(-53.000000, -615.000000)">
        <path d="M76.0071624,615 C62.9300139,615 53,624.094835 53,638.771068 C53,651.451456 62.1984833,663 75.9993379,663 C89.8033224,663 99,651.451456 99,638.771068 C98.9998796,624.111728 89.0845517,615 76.0071624,615 L76.0071624,615 Z M76.0065605,619.240194 C83.4104644,619.240194 84.9162595,629.23899 84.9162595,638.318097 C84.9162595,646.72835 84.078436,657.987728 76.0974451,657.987728 C68.1164542,657.987728 67.0844627,646.618136 67.0844627,638.208583 C67.0844627,629.130175 68.6019344,619.240194 76.0065605,619.240194 L76.0065605,619.240194 Z"></path>
      </g>
    </g>
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="Share" viewBox="0 0 44 44">
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1">
      <g id="Social-Icons---Isolated" transform="translate(-54.000000, -393.000000)">
        <path d="M61.855,422.51 C63.681,422.51 65.363,421.885 66.697,420.838 L81.603,428.197 C81.603,428.227 81.601,428.254 81.601,428.283 C81.601,432.621 85.119,436.139 89.457,436.139 C93.794,436.139 97.312,432.621 97.312,428.283 C97.312,423.946 93.794,420.428 89.457,420.428 C87.148,420.428 85.074,421.422 83.638,423.006 L69.582,416.067 C69.664,415.61 69.71,415.139 69.71,414.656 C69.71,414.559 69.707,414.463 69.703,414.367 L84.244,406.731 C85.632,407.961 87.457,408.711 89.457,408.711 C93.796,408.711 97.312,405.194 97.312,400.856 C97.312,396.516 93.794,393 89.457,393 C85.119,393 81.601,396.516 81.601,400.856 C81.601,401.18 81.625,401.498 81.662,401.811 L67.533,409.231 C66.103,407.735 64.089,406.801 61.855,406.801 C57.517,406.801 54,410.319 54,414.656 C54,418.994 57.517,422.51 61.855,422.51"></path>
      </g>
    </g>
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="twitter" viewBox="0 0 48 39">
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1">
      <g id="Social-Icons---Isolated" transform="translate(-276.000000, -59.000000)">
        <path d="M319.08654,68.7148754 C319.708094,82.5659738 309.37992,98.0092879 291.095386,98.0092879 C285.534424,98.0092879 280.357954,96.3781513 276,93.5841073 C281.223647,94.1997641 286.439039,92.7514374 290.5788,89.505676 C286.270382,89.4266549 282.633053,86.5795371 281.38051,82.6674038 C282.92319,82.9622586 284.441103,82.876161 285.82692,82.4999263 C281.090373,81.5469556 277.822203,77.2809966 277.92835,72.7190034 C279.256376,73.4561404 280.775468,73.8996019 282.390093,73.9491375 C278.003833,71.0194604 276.761905,65.2285125 279.342474,60.8021524 C284.198142,66.7605779 291.453929,70.6809671 299.639098,71.0925844 C298.203745,64.9312988 302.876603,59 309.232493,59 C312.065458,59 314.624797,60.1947516 316.419873,62.1089488 C318.663128,61.6678461 320.77075,60.8481498 322.673153,59.7194457 C321.938375,62.019313 320.376824,63.9500221 318.343506,65.1671827 C320.335545,64.9301194 322.23323,64.4005602 324,63.6174259 C322.68023,65.592953 321.010172,67.3266991 319.08654,68.7148754"></path>
      </g>
    </g>
  </symbol>
</svg>

<svg class="icon">
  <use xlink:href="#MySpace"></use>
</svg>
<svg class="icon">
  <use xlink:href="#opera"></use>
</svg>
<svg class="icon">
  <use xlink:href="#Share"></use>
</svg>
<svg class="icon">
  <use xlink:href="#twitter"></use>
</svg>



